# parse out node and attribute XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xml-libxml

I am trying to search for a value (xxxx01) of an attribute and return the node (0x100540) . Here is my xml:

```
  <model-response-list error="EndOfResults" throttle="86" total-models="86" xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response">
   <model-responses>
      <model mh="0x100540">
         <attribute id="0x1006e">xxxx01</attribute>
      </model>
      <model mh="0x100c80">
         <attribute id="0x1006e">xxx02</attribute>
      </model>
</model-responses>
</model-response-list>
```

I have the xml in an var in the code below:

```
#Get restful req
  $client->setHost('http://wltsvpnms02.aigfpc.com:8080');
  $client->GET('/spectrum/restful/devices?attr=0x1006e', $headers) || die  "$!";
  my $parser     = XML::LibXML->new();
  my $xmldoc     = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $client->responseContent() )|| die "$!";
```

I have tried every xpath search i could find some documentation ( maybe i just cannot get my head around it) on but cannot come up with a solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = '<model-response-list error="EndOfResults" throttle="86" total-models="86" xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response">
   <model-responses>
      <model mh="0x100540">
         <attribute id="0x1006e">xxxx01</attribute>
      </model>
      <model mh="0x100c80">
         <attribute id="0x1006e">xxx02</attribute>
      </model>
</model-responses>
</model-response-list>';

my $xmldoc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );

my @nodes = $xmldoc->findnodes(q(//*[text()='xxxx01']/../@mh));

foreach (@nodes) {
  say $_->value;
}
```

My XPath is a bit rusty. There might be a better solution.

Comment: indeed it does! Thanks a bunch !

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is almost certainly the

```
xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response"
```

Unprefixed element names in XPath refer to elements that are not in a namespace, whereas all the elements in your document are in the `http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response` namespace, so the obvious paths like

```
//model[attribute = 'xxxx01']
```

will fail.  You need to use an `XPathContext` to handle the namespace:

```
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xmldoc);
$xc->registerNs('resp', 'http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response');
my @nodes = $xc->findnodes('//resp:model[resp:attribute = "xxxx01"]');
```

using the prefix you passed to `registerNs` in the XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

Good choice on [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) per advice on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25409509/1733163).

If there wasn't a namespace, your goal could be solved as easily as:

```
my $mh = $xmldoc->findvalue('//model[attribute = "xxxx01"]/@mh');
```

However, one of the more challenging things to navigate XML wise are namespaces, as is specified by the `xmlns` attribute of the root node.

There are two approaches that I can recommend for solving this:

1. Register the namespace before querying using [`XML::LibXML::XPathContext`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::XPathContext).

   The following requires that you know the namespace URI in advance.

   ```
   use XML::LibXML;
   use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

   my $xmldoc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $string);
   my $context = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $xmldoc->documentElement() );
   $context->registerNs( 'u' => 'http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response' );

   my $mh = $context->findvalue('//u:model[u:attribute = "xxxx01"]/@mh');
   print "$mh\n";
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   0x100540
   ```

   However, it's also possible to determine the namespace if you don't want to hardcode the URI:

   ```
   my $ns = ( $xmldoc->documentElement()->getNamespaces() )[0]->getValue();
   $context->registerNs( 'u' => $ns );
   ```
2. Use the [`local-name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name) function to query ignoring namespaces:

   This makes for a longer XPath, but also takes less setup:

   ```
   use XML::LibXML;

   my $xmldoc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $string);

   my $mh = $xmldoc->findvalue('//*[local-name() = "model"]/*[local-name() = "attribute"][text() = "xxxx01"]/../@mh');
   print "$mh\n";
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   0x100540
   ```

Don't feel discouraged if it takes a little while to absorb the [XPath](http://w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) syntax and the framework of [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML).  I consider namespaces advanced topics, and even had a ask [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25419772/1733163) with regard to them myself yesterday.

Fortunately, no amount of learning curve would take up the amount of time that you'll save avoiding bugs that [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) would introduce.